# How can I get rid of a lot of wisps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So I think I placed a quarry near a corrupt node, which meant it got chunk loaded. There are... a few wisps now...

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of them, or should I leave this forsaken place and take my quarries elsewhere?

Comment: Encase the node in blocks, disassemble the quarry, walk a couple chunks away and wait until they despawn, then set up a wisp grinder with a chunkloader/quarry? :)

Comment: The node is right there, at the thaumcraft altar. And yes, it is an evil node. Guaranteed. Wow.

Comment: Oh, wow. I'd just leave it to them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have Mystcraft available in your FTB pack, going elsewhere would likely be the easiest thing to do.

However to address the wisp issue I would suggest doing a little bit of Thaumcraft to get the goggles that let you see the node. The nodes are like any other spawner except they are not affected by light level. You can build a little cage around the buggers and then either ignore them or take care of them at your own pace... with a bucket of Lava.

EDIT: One thing to keep in mind is that cooping up a lot of entities into a single area can have very bad results on a server. The wisps never seem to get more than a dozen or so when kept near their nodes, but if you notice some lag in the area of a contained node then it is time for some lava.

Comment: Note that going to another Mystcraft age won't despawn them, as the chunks will unload, and unloaded chunks don't check for (de)spawning. Going elsewhere to set up new quarries is certainly the safest option, though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I just meant to up and move the quarry elsewhere might be easiest.

Comment: Yeah. It's a bit ambiguous though, so I noted that for readers who got the wrong meaning from "go elsewhere".

Answer (score 1):

The wisps aren't spawning from the node. There is a wisp spawner under the altar (it used to be zombie pigmen). if you take out that spawner, then the number of wisps in the area will decline quickly. Then pick up a ranged weapon and pick them off (all of that wisp essence will be great if you plan on doing thaumcraft).

Comment: also i should add if you plant a silverwood nearby (but not so close that the nodes merge) it will generate a pure node that will eat the flux the corrupt node generates, at relatively the same rate.